# Advanced Search: Exporting Groups/tags fields from event participant search

Tags: civievent, civimember

When using advanced search to find event participants, the option to export Group(s) and Tags is not listed under "individual record type". Is there a way to pull this data together with event participant fields?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible work around is to do the search twice, first search will be to add the contacts to a temporal group and export contacts with the right tags and groups, the second search, export the events related data and use excel function example Vlookup to add tags/groups to your last export. You may want to export the contact ID, which will be your unique column for Vlookup.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, at least without resorting to spreadsheet trickery like Kboy suggests.  You have a few options:
* Commission a custom report, or for a modification to the current reports to export the data you want.
* Restructure your data to use custom fields rather than groups/tags.  You can always use smart groups based on your custom fields if you need to keep the groups for, e.g., mailings or other searches.